# Clustering using longitude, latitude, and some other variable

Tags: machine-learning, clustering

I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction with this problem I am having.

I am trying to cluster geographical areas (basically using latitude and longitude as the zip code centroid) which have the highest number of deaths in a given state. But, the added constraint is that those clustered areas have to be touching.

For example, if California has 1000 deaths and Nevada has 1000 deaths, and all other states have 0, then California and Nevada should be cluster 1 while all other states should be cluster 2.

However, if California has 1000 deaths and Texas has 1000 deaths, and all other states have 0, then California should be cluster 1, Texas should be cluster 2, while all other states should be cluster 3.

This is a bit of a simplification because I'm trying to do this exercise at the zip code level. However, the point is that I want proximity to matter. Does anyone know of a method that can achieve this result?

Comment: It is possible to invent an _ad hoc_ proximity measure that is greatly amplified if the two regions are adjacent and downright attenuated if they are not. Play with, for example, exponentiation.